# How to query results from multiple tables in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two tables

```
let SalesItemsSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    quantity : {type:Number , required:true},
    sale_id: {type: String, required: true},
    amount : {type:Number , required:true},
    purchase_amount : {type:Number , required:true},
} , {timestamps : true});

let InventorySchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true, max: 100},
    quantity: {type: Number, required: true},
} , {timestamps:true});
```

I want to get the remaining items in the inventory. For example 100 items of something were added to the inventory and 90 of them were sold. 
i want to get the difference from two tables (which will be 10) 
i am using mongoose.